# MVC master-detail with different detail types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Folks,

Environment: ASP .NET MVC 4

In the view that I need to build, there needs to be two sections. The top section shows a table. Based on the row selected by the user, I need to render an appropriate user interface in the bottom section. Essentially, it is a master-detail view except that the controls in the detail change based on the selected row in the master section.

I am guessing I need to create partial views corresponding to each of the detail type and somehow programmatically show the right view.

I would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me on what the proper approach would be. Any sample code or links to existing examples would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: If you check the default ASP.NET MVC Template it comes with a project that does exactly that, unless you mean to load the contents with AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely multiple ways of doing this, one would be to create a dedicated `Action` in your `Controller` for each master-detail scenario:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Detail1(Model model)
     {
         return View(model);
     }

     public ActionResult Detail2(Model model)
     {
         return View(model);
     }
}
```

Next you would create a reusable `Partial` for the master table, and depending on your logic, trigger the correct `Action` (pseudo-code):

```
<td>
    @if (<your logic for the detailed view to be displayed>)
    {
        Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Detail1");
    }
    else
    {
        Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Detail2");
    }
</td>
```

You would render the master table from both `Detail1` and `Detail2` views.
Hope I've understood you correctly. Cheers!

**Update - Ajax**

If you don't want the entire page to be updated when a new detail is shown you could use the `Ajax.ActionLink` in the master table and change the `HomeController` methods to return `PartialView` for each detail type.

```
<td>
    @if (<your logic for the detailed view to be displayed>)
    {
       Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Detail1", options);
    }
    else
    {
       Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Detail2", options);
    }
</td>
```

Where `options` specify the `UpdateTargetId` of the div that should be replaced with the detail view returned from the controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Master()
     {
         return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Detail1()
     {
         return PartialView();
     }

     public ActionResult Detail2()
     {
         return PartialView();
     }
}
```

Finally, include the `jquery.unobtrusive` script in the master view (which resides by default in the `~/bundles/jqueryval` bundle):

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem with ActionLink is that it will cause a new page to be displayed. I would like my data to appear below the master list. I am accepting this answer as you are close. I will use RenderPartial to display what I need.

Comment: Sure, you could also use Ajax.ActionLink, I will update my answer for completeness.